# Exchanging labels after click of a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on a GUI that is going to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius and show it in different ways. If the Celcius ends up being positive (+3) the window is going to turn red. If the temp is negative (-58) the window is going to become purple. I managed to code the base window with a button that converts correctly, but I cannot get the window to change label.

It is supposed to go from the green main window to one that says "The converted temperature: " and display the results.

Perhaps you can aid me in how to do this. Posting the code as it is now.

```
#GUI for the fahrenheit calculator.

import tkinter

class MyConverterGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame()    
        #self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        self.main_window.title("Konverterare")
        self.main_window.geometry("350x350") 

        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, text= 'Fahrenheit till Celcius-konverterare' '\n' 'Skriv in ett tal och tryck på Omvandla' , \
                                  width = 90, height = 20, bg = "green")

        self.label1.pack()

        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.bottom_frame, text= "Skriv in en temperatur(f) här ---->")
        self.fhentry = tkinter.Entry(self.bottom_frame, width = 10)

        self.prompt_label.pack(side="left")
        self.fhentry.pack(side="left")

        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.c_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, textvariable = self.value)
        self.value.set("Graderna omvandlade: ")

        self.c_label.pack()

        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text ="Omvandla", bg ="purple", command=self.convert, \
                                          height = 2, width = 17)
        self.calc_button.pack(side="right")

        self.top_frame.pack()
        #self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def ersattEtikett(self):
        self.nyText=convert()
        self.bytText.set(nytext)

    def importera(self):
        self.fahrenheit = float(self.fhentry.get())

        return self.fahrenheit

    def convert(self):
        self.fahrenheit = self.importera()
        self.Celcius = float(self.fahrenheit - 32)*(5/9)
        self.Celcius = round(self.Celcius, 2)
        print ("Detta funkade fint", self.Celcius)

        return self.Celcius

my_converter = MyConverterGUI()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't know how conversion works at all:

```
def ersattEtikett(self):
    self.nyText = self.convert()  #Shouldn't it be `self.convert()`???
    self.bytText.set(nytext)
```

Now, as far as setting the changing the background of the label, all you need to do is use the `config` method:

```
self.whatever_label_here.config(bg='red')
```

Using `.config`, you can change the attributes that you can set in the constructor.  For example:

```
self.label1.config(text="This is the new label text",bg="green")
```

Finally, as a note of style:

```
self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text ="Omvandla", bg ="purple", command=self.convert, \
                                  height = 2, width = 17)
```

In the previous line, the backslash (`\`) is completely unnecessary.  Python will automatically continue lines where any type of parenthesis isn't closed --

```
mylist = [ 1,
           2,
           3 ]
```

is completely valid (although I'm not saying you should write all your lists this way!).  As is:

```
mydict = { 'foo': 'bar',
           'bar': 'baz',
           'baz': 'qux' }
```

as is:

```
mycallable(foo,
           bar,
           baz,
           qux="A cat in a hat")
```

---

*Aside -- A quick blurb about `self`*

You can create an instance of a class by "calling" a class:

```
foo = MyClass()
```

Now you can call a method on `foo` by calling it:

```
bar = foo.method()
```

Note that to get access to the method, you need to know `foo`.  `bar = method()` wouldn't work (nor would you expect it to).  So, how does this work if you want to call a method inside `foo` from another method inside `foo`?  That's where `self` comes in:  Consider the following class definition:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar =  'baz'

    def method(self):
        print( "ID of self:", id(self) )
        return self.method2()

    def method2(self):
        self.bar = 'qux'
        return self.bar

foo = MyClass()
print ( "ID of foo:", id(foo) )
foo.method()
```

Notice that the ID of `foo` is the same as the ID of `self`.  In other words, `foo` gets passed as the first argument to it's method (which we name `self` as a convention).  Another way to look at it:

```
foo.method()
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
MyClass.method(foo)
```

Comment: Truthfully, I am not sure either - a friend told me to use that method.

Comment: @user1916173 -- Oh, I see it now.  When you construct `self.calc_button`'s you set `command=self.convert`.  So, when you click that button, the `convert` method is called correctly, but nothing else happens.  Apparently, the `ersattEtikett` method is never called.  If you changed it to `command=self.ersattEtikket`, you'd see an error unless you made the change that I recommended above.

Comment: Oh, yes. Right. Ahh, now I understand why nothing happens then. What change did you do exactly? I can see it but I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @user1916173 -- I suppose I am proposing 2 changes.  You change `command=self.convert` to `command=self.self.ersattEtikket` in `self.calc_button`.  Now when you click the button, `ersattEtikket` will be called instead of `convert`.  This is fine because `ersattEtikket` calls `convert` with my second change:  `self.nyText = self.convert()` where I added `self` on the right hand side.  You need `self` so that python knows how to find the method.  I'll add a quick blurb on `self` to my answer as It would be too hard to do in a comment.

Comment: @user1916173 -- Answer updated with a quick explanation about `self` and what it actually is.

Comment: I understand fully and I did what you said. However, I get this error now:
{ Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\testförGUI.py", line 48, in ersattEtikett
    self.value.set(nytext)
NameError: global name 'nytext' is not defined }

Comment: Yeah, python would be right about that.  I was just following the form of your original code.  I'm guessing what you actually want is:  `nytext = self.convert()` and then `self.value.set(nytext)`

Comment: The program is now working as it should, however, I do not get a different label but instead it remains on the same one and shows the result underneath top_frame. 

How do I make it so the label changes to another one?

Comment: I want the new label to superceed the current label1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22064/discussion-between-mgilson-and-user1916173)